# libpq client crashes inside PQclear()

Tags: postgresql

To start off, here's the client code:

```
PGresult    *res;
const char  *values[1] = { user_name };
const int   lengths[1] = { strlen(user_name) };
const int   formats[1] = { 0 };
void        *data = 0;
AccountData *ad = 0;

res = PQexecPrepared(conn, "SELECT_ACCOUNT", 1, values, lengths, formats, 1);
if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK || PQntuples(res) != 1 || (data = (void*)PQgetvalue(res, 0, 0)) == 0) {
    PQclear(res);
    return 0;
}
else {
    ad = deserializeAccountData(data);
    PQclear(res); // <- Crashes here
    return ad;
}
```

Here's the address/code it's crashing at:
[image: IDA]
Which I believe is equivalent of code below(from libpq Github):

```
/* Free all the subsidiary blocks */
while ((block = res->curBlock) != NULL)
{
    res->curBlock = block->next;
    free(block);
}
```

Also worth to mention that these crashes don't always happen. I execute same function thousands of times on entire dataset with hopes of reproducing the issue with no results. Everything is single threaded.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated as I have no clue left at this point.

Comment: What does the `ad = deserializeAccountData(data);` function call do? It could be that this function keeps pointers to the data inside `res`. (or mutilates something inside `res`). [start by commenting the functioncall out and see if the crash disappears]

Comment: @joop But I don't get the crash when I test this function with all entries in database. Correct me if I'm wrong but if this function was faulty and was causing the crash for one(or more) entry, shouldn't it also cause a crash next time I load all entries?

Comment: No, as Daniel V pointed out it could be the result of an unititialized variable. Or a spurious memory overwrite, or an off-by-some.

Answer (score 0):

This crash is the delayed result of a bug that occurs in the program before the call to `PQclear()`. The effect of the bug is to overwrite pointers in the linked list that libpq has allocated.

In some cases, [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or similar memory checker tools help to figure out quickly the origin of such bugs.

Comment: I've added additional logging for the linked list. It includes same pointers prior to PQclear call as it does after PQexecPrepared.

Comment: @AcarX: in the non-crashing case I presume. But observing the non-crashing case does not necessarily help with hard-to-reproduce bugs. For example, if the problem is triggered by an uninitialized variable having a specific value in the heap or in the stack.

Comment: In crashing case. I print out pointer addresses for linked list elements and initial elements are same as elements prior to PQclear call.

Comment: @AcarX: so what do you conclude? that `free(block)` destroys `res->curBlock`? That still leads nowhere in terms of finding a bug in that area of the code.

Comment: After further debugging, I've discovered that the crash is happening inside free() call with first linked list element being the parameter.